# django Error when upload the file from the admin panel

Tags: django, upload

Hello I have problem when upload large file more than 30MB approximately from the admin panel
otherwise the browser throws

> "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading"

on Firefox or

> "Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): Unknown error"

on Chrome.

Comment: This is probably a server issue. How is your server set up and what are you using?

Comment: Default? What server are you using? Are you developing locally?

Comment: I'm Using dedicated server from hostgator.com
and on locally I Don't Have problem

Comment: Ask HostGator what limits do they have for upload size and script timeout

Answer (score 2):

This problem should be the Upload limit on Web server, try to increase it.

If you are using NGinx, add `client_max_body_size 35m;` at http block or change the value if exists.

Maybe you can increase using a .htaccess file on Apache Web Server.